# How to use legends from PlotLegends in LevelScheme?

Tags: plotting, graphics, version-9, legending, levelscheme

I've been attempting to find efficient ways to generate graphics with legends for export, and have been working with both `LevelScheme` and the new (to v9) `PlotLegends`.  It seems the easiest approach would be to use `PlotLegends` to automatically generate the legends with the graphic, peel out the plots and legends separately, then use `LevelScheme` to arrange/combine as desired.  Sounds pretty painless, but...

The `RawGraphics` command of `LevelScheme` does not accept MMA's `LineLegend`, etc. objects.  The only workaround I've found is to wrap the legend in `Graphics[Inset[...]]`, but this breaks down, as `LevelScheme` dumps these graphics objects in the middle of the `MultiPanel` area.

Any ideas on how to get this working (or maybe why it cannot work)?  Below is my attempt so far:

```
Get["LevelScheme`"];

myPlot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 72*3, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend["Expressions"], {After, Center}]];
Graphics[Inset[myPlot[[2, 1, 1]]], ImagePadding -> None, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True]

myDensity = 
  DensityPlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, {y, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> 72*3, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic];
Graphics[Inset[myDensity[[2, 1, 1]]], ImagePadding -> None, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True]

Figure[
 {
  Multipanel[
   {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
   {2, 2},
   XPlotRanges -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}},
   YPlotRanges -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}
   ],
  FigurePanel[{1, 1}],
  RawGraphics[myPlot[[1]]],
  FigurePanel[{2, 1}],
  RawGraphics[myDensity[[1]]],
  FigurePanel[{1, 2}],
  RawGraphics[
   Graphics[Inset[myPlot[[2, 1, 1]]], ImagePadding -> None, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> True]],
  FigurePanel[{2, 2}],
  RawGraphics[
   Graphics[Inset[myDensity[[2, 1, 1]]], ImagePadding -> None, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> True]],
  },
 PlotRange -> Automatic,
 ExtendRange -> {{0.1, 0.1}, {0.15, 0.1}},
 ImageSize -> 6*72, Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the OP's hack works is because `Inset` allows to place non-graphic objects in a graphics object. The reason it does not work is because `Inset` places the inset in the center of hosting graph by default.

The package has a command to include non-graphics objects: `ScaledLabel`.

The following function takes a legend plot `p`and returns the command to include it in a `Figure` at the location `l` with the scaling `s`. The location is respect to the original graph.

```
transformLegendPlot[p_, l_, s_: 1] := 
  Sequence[RawGraphics@p[[1]], 
   ScaledLabel[l, 
    p[[2, 1, 1]] /. (LegendMarkerSize -> x_) :> 
      LegendMarkerSize -> s x]];
```

Now, `transformLegendPlot` can be used almost as a native command:

```
Figure[{Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {2, 1}, XPlotRanges -> {{0, 10}},
    YPlotRanges -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}], FigurePanel[{1, 1}], 
  transformLegendPlot[myPlot, {0.5, 0.7}], FigurePanel[{2, 1}], 
  transformLegendPlot[myDensity, {0.2, 0.5}, .5]}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, ExtendRange -> {{0.1, 0.1}, {0.15, 0.1}}, 
 ImageSize -> 6*72, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

---

**Update**

Extracting and formatting the legends `PlotLegends` (for use in LevelScheme).

The OP mentions in a comment that the plot legends should be posted in a different pane. Since that seems to have been his original intent, I will oblige.

The following code produces a `ScaledLabel` object to be used in a different panel with the addition that the style of the legends can be changed.

```
extractLegendsAndFormat[plot_, scale_, styles___] := 
  ScaledLabel[{0.5, 0.5}, 
   plot[[2, 1, 1]] /. 
     x : TraditionalForm[HoldForm[_]] :> 
      Style[x, styles] /. (LegendMarkerSize -> x_) :> 
     LegendMarkerSize -> scale x];
```

Now, you can give format options as shown below:

```
l1 := extractLegendsAndFormat[myPlot, 1, FontName -> "Helvetica", 
  FontSize -> 33, FontColor -> Red];
l2 := extractLegendsAndFormat[myDensity, 0.5];
```

Those objects can be placed in their own panels:

```
Figure[{Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {2, 2}, XPlotRanges -> {{0, 10}},
    YPlotRanges -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}],
  FigurePanel[{1, 1}], RawGraphics@myPlot[[1]],
  FigurePanel[{1, 2}], l1, 
  FigurePanel[{2, 1}], RawGraphics@myDensity[[1]], 
  FigurePanel[{2, 2}], l2}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 ExtendRange -> {{0.1, 0.1}, {0.15, 0.1}}, ImageSize -> 6*72, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

---

**Previous answer**

300 reputation is too good to let it go, so here is my second try. It still uses `Overlay`.

```
ff = Figure[{Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {2, 2}, 
     XPlotRanges -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}, 
     YPlotRanges -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}], FigurePanel[{1, 1}], 
    RawGraphics[myPlot[[1]]], FigurePanel[{2, 1}], 
    RawGraphics[myDensity[[1]]], FigurePanel[{1, 2}], 
    FigurePanel[{2, 2}]}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
   ExtendRange -> {{0.1, 0.1}, {0.15, 0.1}}, ImageSize -> 6*72, 
   Frame -> True];

Manipulate[
 Overlay[{ff, 
   Graphics[{Opacity[0], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], Opacity[1], 
     Inset[myPlot[[2, 1, 1]], {x, y}]}], 
   Graphics[{Opacity[0], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], Opacity[1], 
     Inset[myDensity[[2, 1, 1]], {.94, .618}]}]}], {{x,.45}, 0, 1}, {{y,.8}, 0, 
  1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I will update this answer in a couple of days. LevelScheme updates the coordinates of each pane but it does not update the coordinates of the `Inset`. Fortunately, `Inset` can use either coordinates respect to the original plot or respect to the container.

Comment: Thanks for your time!  I'm just curious: you say in your post that this is your second try.  I'm just curious: what was your first try?

Comment: @Andrew: I posted a solution using `Column` and `Overlay` to produce a layout similar to the OP's but with a lot more control (but less special effects). A fellow poster with 50K reputation made me realize that your question specifically asks about the package LevelScheme.

Comment: Oh, ok, so your original answer is no longer posted?  Or is it the first section of your answer above?

Comment: @Andrew: I deleted my first post because it did not address fully the OP's question. The first section above is the update that I mentioned in a previous comment. With `transformLegendPlot`, you specify the coordinates of the legend respect to the scaled coordinates of the *original* graphic. It also allows you to scale the legend of a density plot. The resulting commands must be used with LevelScheme. I think that completes the requests from OP, doesn't it?

Comment: @Hector Nice!  Extra nice with the legend scaling.  I hate to mooch, but it's going to take me some time to make sure I understand what you're doing (still learning mma)...do you think the following are possible with this method:  1) Have text styles/fonts set in the `LevelScheme` environment apply to the legend text, 2) Put the legend in its own `FigurePanel`?  Those are lower priorities for sure, but I can't imagine a use-case that wouldn't be covered that way.

Comment: (1) Yes, (2) Yes. I will update my answer later.

Comment: I like it!  `LevelScheme`+`PlotLegends` sure does automate a lot of the work.  The option to put the legends in another panel adds a lot of flexibility too.

Comment: @Hector Thanks so much!  Great job!

Answer (score 4):

I think the "easiest" way is to abandon the use of `LevelScheme` to position your legend. Instead, I would do something like this,

```
legend = myplot /. Legended[_, Placed[l_, ___]|{Placed[l_, ___]}] :> l;

Legended[
  Figure[ (* fill in details *),
  Placed[ legend, placement ]
]
```

Comment: This is ok if you're using only one figure, but gets cumbersome for multipanel figures. Also, `PlotLegends` doesn't support (AFAIK) legends inside the plot area, which is more economical (space wise) than outside.

Comment: @rm-rf If there is only a single legend, then this method works just fine. Also, `Placed` accepts numerical positions, too, so placing it inside the plot is just fine.

Comment: Yes...all around.  The built-in `PlotLegends` with `Placed` (using numerical positioning) is definitely the most efficient, automated way I've found to get a legend on a plot.  However, all the forums I've read, as well as my own experience thus far, indicate that `LevelScheme` is the most efficient way to arrange multiple graphics for publication/export.  I'm a long way from mastering all of MMA's graphics functions...I'm hoping there's some function in there that'll cause `LevelScheme` to just accept the legend as it would any other graph.

Comment: @brad you could try Rasterize.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach your problem, firstly by dropping all legends from your plots.  As an example, your density plot would be redefined as

```
myDensity = DensityPlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, {y, -1, 1}];
```

and I would define a bar legend using another density plot:

```
lgDensity = 
 DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["LakeColors"]
  ]
```

Everything after this is stock, standard level scheme.  One presentation using your input and level scheme is

```
Figure[{
  SetOptions[SchemeObject, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
   FontSize -> 10],
  Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {2, 2},
   XPlotRanges -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}, 
   YPlotRanges -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}},
   XFrameLabels -> {"X Axis", ""},
   YFrameLabels -> {"Label 1", "Label 2"},
   YGapSizes -> 0.05, XGapSizes -> .05,
   BufferB -> 5, BufferL -> 7,
   Margin -> 45,
   YPanelSizes -> {1, 1},
   XPanelSizes -> {0.98, .05}
   ],
  FigurePanel[{1, 1}],
  RawGraphics[myPlot[[1]]],
  FigurePanel[{2, 1}],
  RawGraphics[myDensity],
  FigurePanel[{2, 2}, ShowPanelLetter -> False, 
   ShowTickLabels -> {False, False, False, True}, 
   XPlotRange -> {0, 1}, YPlotRange -> {-1, 1}],
  RawGraphics@lgDensity
  },
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Frame -> True]
```

which, to my eyes anyway, is considerably cleaner than your example.  YMMV.

As other responders have pointed out, you can easily add more `ScaledLabel[]`'s in the appropriate frame.

Comment: You make a good point in favor of a more straightforward approach.  I keep debating that point with myself, but in the end I like having MMA automatically pull all the color/line data, etc. from the graphic into the legend.  Definitely a matter of taste though.