# Too much whitespace in a GraphicsGrid containing Legended Plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

Where is all the vertical whitespace coming from, and how do I get rid of it?

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend["Expressions"], {1, 0.5}]];
GraphicsGrid[{{plot, plot}, {plot, plot}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Okay, `AspectRatio` is definitely the key for the `GraphicsGrid` option (which I'm pursuing in case I don't want to rasterize).  It seems I get rid of all whitespace if:

1. Use `AspectRatio->Full` in both the plot and the `GraphicsGrid`
2. Use numerical placement of the legends...not tags like "Before", etc.

What I've come up with so far would get with hairy frame labels, or tick/legend text that varied in length, but I think those things are beyond the scope of this post:

```
leftPlot = 
  Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All,
    AspectRatio -> Full, Background -> Green, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 10.5}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend["Expressions"], {{0, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}}]];
rightPlot = 
  Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All,
    AspectRatio -> Full, Background -> Green, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 10.5}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend["Expressions"], {{1, 0.5}, {0, 0.5}}]];
GraphicsGrid[
 {{
   Show[leftPlot, 
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, Automatic}}],
   Show[rightPlot, 
    ImagePadding -> {{None, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}}]
   },
  {
   Show[leftPlot, 
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}],
   Show[rightPlot, 
    ImagePadding -> {{None, Automatic}, {Automatic, None}}]
   }},
 Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> Full, 
 ImageSize -> 72*{8, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Adjust `AspectRatio` parameter inside your `Plot` function. For example `AspectRatio -> 1`. Maybe move your legend down.

Comment: You could try `Grid` instead of `GraphicsGrid`.

Answer (score 15):

You might consider using `Grid` in place of `GraphicsGrid`. Doing so comes with both pluses and minuses, so it is not a no-brain choice. However, `Grid` will accommodate any shape and size of display object automatically. When putting plots in a grid, I find it is usually best to set `ImageSize` in the plot explicitly.

Using your example plot at `Medium` size

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10},
  Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend["Expressions"], {1, 0.5}]]
Grid[{{plot, plot}, {plot, plot}},
 Frame -> All, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

give this

[image: plot.png]

You can see there is no wasted space.

Comment: That does look a lot better.  I take it one of the minuses you allude to is that `Grid` cannot be exported as an image the way `GraphicsGrid` can?  Good trick to know in any case.

Comment: @brad You can export it just the same, after running the code above `Export["grid.png", %]` pretty much everything can be exported as an image thanks to `Rasterize`

Answer (score 12):

The main problem is that the aspect ratio of the plot and its container are different. You can still use `GraphicsGrid` with the correct settings:

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend["Expressions"], {.5, 0.5}], 
   Background -> Green, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio];
GraphicsGrid[{{plot, plot}, {plot, plot}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, 
 Frame -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

By the way, have you seen [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34335/8803) to your other question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why would one want to place the legend in the middle of a plot...?

Comment: The placement of the legend in this particular post is bad, and so is background color; both were done so on purpose.The awful background helps to identify those pixels wasted by other reasons. Try `Spacings` with negative numbers to remove them. The placement of the legends was obnoxiously placed in the middle to indicate that extra space can be saved by placing the legend inside the graph. You might want to find a better place for it.

Comment: @Hector Yes, I'm looking over that now.  You can probably guess that my overall concern is how to keep the convenience of `PlotLegends` in situations where I want arrays of plots...To `LevelScheme` or not to `LevelScheme`, that is the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since there still is no accepted answer, although some good ones were given, I try and give my contribution.

While trying to solve a problem similar to yours, I came across [this page](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/) where it is explained how to realise a grid of plots as follows:

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
ImageSize -> Medium, 
PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"]]

ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 { {plot,plot} , {plot,plot} }, 
 Spacings -> 25,
 PlotLabels -> {
   Placed[{"top left"}, {Left, Above}],
   Placed[{"top right"}, {Center, Above}],
   "Label 3",
   "Last Label"
   }
 ]
```

This results in the following plot:
[image: Example plot]

As you can see, the legends of each plot are collected, but that is an easy one to fix:

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 {
  {
   Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> Medium, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[ "Expressions", {1, .5}]],
   Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> Medium]
   },
  {
   Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> Medium]
   }
  },
 Spacings -> 30,
 PlotLabels -> {
   Placed[{"top left"}, {Left, Above}],
   Placed[{"top right"}, {Center, Above}],
   "Label 3",
   "Last Label"
   }
 ]
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add an image of the result?

Comment: @Syed I have edited my answer. Sorry, I firstly posted the answer in a rush :)

Comment: It is more beneficial for visitors to the page this way. Many thanks.