# Combining plots using GraphicsGrid with a centered image above two images

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am having trouble combining images using GraphicsGrid. My question is similar to [Too much whitespace in a GraphicsGrid containing Legended Plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34221/45020) but it seems more complicated because I want to have one image centered above two other images for which I use `SpanFromLeft` (perhaps not the right tool?).

Can anyone explain how I should pick the image sizes and aspect ratios so that they are roughly the same for every individual plot and with as little white space between the plots as possible.

The closest I could get was:

```
imageSize = 600;
GraphicsGrid[{{ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], 
    ImageSize -> imageSize*Sqrt[2], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], 
   SpanFromLeft}, {ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], 
    ImageSize -> imageSize, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], 
   ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], ImageSize -> imageSize, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]}}, ImageSize -> 1000
 , AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
 ]
```

I have no idea why I would need to multiply by Sqrt[2] in the top plot to get a similarly sized image as the others. It probably has to do with me combining two cells using  SpanFromLeft.

Comment: There are many questions on this site about [PlotGrid](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/) which could be what you want.

Comment: Hmm perhaps. If Built-in functions can do what I want I would prefer that. But perhaps PlotGrid is the better tool. I don't know.

Comment: Do you _really_ need `GraphicsGrid`? If you simply use `Grid`, it works perfectly as expected: `imageSize = 300; Grid[{{ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], ImageSize -> imageSize], SpanFromLeft}, {ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], ImageSize -> imageSize], ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], ImageSize -> imageSize]}}]`

Comment: @Domen, right it has been suggested before that GraphicsGrid might just be a bad function and we should use Grid as an alternative. GraphicsGrid seems intuitively closer to what I want though. I would prefer an image that I can rescale with ImageSize. I also don't know whether Grid would export correctly as one image (perhaps it does I never tried or looked into it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you can just leave away the `ImageSize` specifications:

```
GraphicsGrid[
 {
  {
   ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], Frame -> True],
   SpanFromLeft
   }, {
   ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], Frame -> True], 
   ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], Frame -> True]
   }
  },
 ImageSize -> 600, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Spacings -> 0
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Indeed that works. Do you understand why it works? Is it because the default ImageSize is somehow the correct one to combine at this AspectRatio or is it because not specifying leaves MMA more free to pick it a the end?

Comment: `AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio` is default setting btw

Comment: @Kvothe Unfortunately, I don't know how exactly `GraphicsGrid` decides on the size of things..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hack that works with arbitrary ImageSize:

```
imageSize = 300;
Column[{
  Row[{Graphics@Text[""], 
    ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], ImageSize -> imageSize, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], Graphics@Text[""]}, 
   StringRepeat[" ", Round[imageSize/12]]], 
  Row[{ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], ImageSize -> imageSize, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], 
    ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}], ImageSize -> imageSize, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]}]}]
```

[image]