# LevelScheme Ticks hidden behind DensityPlot or SmoothDensityHistogram

Tags: plotting

I'm having a problem where the LevelScheme ticks are hidden by my `SmoothDensityHistogram`.

[image]

In the above figure, I am sure that the ticks are there since you can see the ones that are not hidden by the discrete `DensityHistogram` in the figure below.

[image]

It seems that LevelScheme is ignoring `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1]` since it's calling the plot with RawGraphics.

It also seem to be a common issue since a quick LevelScheme search on StackExchange shows a few graphs with the same issue:

1) [How to use legends from PlotLegends in LevelScheme?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33863/how-to-use-legends-from-plotlegends-in-levelscheme)

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429204/how-do-i-create-subplots-in-mathematica-using-levelscheme

Perhaps adding some transparency to my `ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, ColorData["Temperature"][height]]` but I can't find out how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check this:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28025/how-to-draw-grid-lines-on-top-of-a-plot

Comment: Thank @DavidG.Stork. It looks like `Method -> {"FrameInFront" -> False}` is what I need.  Do you know how to use with the LevelScheme package?

Answer (score 1):

After contacting the developer of the LevelScheme package, there is an easy fix to this problem. I just need to add `Layer->-1` in the `RawGraphics` of LevelScheme.
So:

```
      RawGraphics[SmoothDensityHistogram[...], Layer->-1],
```

This places the raw graphics below the frames.